# What pattern should I use to load data from remote sources in Asp.Net apps?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, web-services, caching

My Asp.Net MVC 5 application loads content (articles, news, etc) from a remote SaaS product that offers the writing room using API calls so I don't have to deal with it myself.

At first we were going to load this data on a per-call basis, but since the data changes once a day or less (articles are not added all the time) I decided to load everything up front using lazy load so when the first call comes in ALL content entities are loaded and cached using MemoryCache.

Right now we have about 20 different entities with about 1000 total instances so it's not a big deal regarding the cache size. However, in order to load all these instances I need to make about 80 remote calls and some logic to mix related content like *once all articles are loaded, loop through them so their RelatedArticles properties are filled*.

My problem right now is that when the application is deployed (causing app pool to flush everything) or started locally the initial load time is huge (from 60 to 120 seconds).

I'm sure I have some local optimizations I can do to reduce the load time by improving some of the content mixing logic, but my biggest question is **should I continue to use lazy load when bringing this data in or should I use a different pattern to try to make this better**?

Comment: Why not use a scheduled job to retrieve and process your data, then store it in DB and work with this DB in the app?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I use the SaaS product exactly to avoid this hassle. But let's follow your thought. I would still have to load the data on a per-call/per-page basis getting back at this same problem of "how do I cache this data"?

Comment: Calling local database with all the data that is ready is probably faster than calling a service, so even if app pool recycles your data will be loaded faster. Another solution might be to use external cache like Redis, that will not depend on app pool recycling

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions.

1) Is your remote SaaS solution fast enough? In other words, what is faster - load from that solution or from some storage you own? If calling your storage is faster, then create a worker that would pull the remote SaaS solution and put the retrieved data in your storage.

2) If the all content size is small, pre-cache everything.

3) If you cannot precache everything because of its size, see if you can get any statistics what's more popular content and what's less so that you can precache the most popular articles, etc.